# Car insurance for Northern Cyprus

Tags: car-rentals, insurance, cyprus, northern-cyprus

I'm planning to rent a car in the Republic of Cyprus, and then, travel to the Northern Cyprus. [Budget](http://www.budget.com.cy/budgetonline/cy-gb/budget.nsf/c/footernavigation,terms_and_conditions) doesn't allow to travel to the Northern Cyprus, so either Europcar or Sixt is my choice. However, their insurance doesn't cover northern part of the island.

Europcar:

> No insurance cover whatsoever is provided if a vehicle is driven into the occupied Northern Area of the island. ([link](https://www.europcar.com.cy/pages/europcar-cyprus-terms-conditions))

Sixt:

> None of the protections covers the use of a vehicle in the North of Cyprus. ([link](https://www.sixt.com/rental-information/#/))

As I read in the forums and blog posts, there's a required fee for car insurance at the border which costs either €20 (3 days) or €35 (1 week) paid in cash.

My questions are—

1. How can I buy full car insurance (the one that would cover full damage) for Northern Cyprus? Are there any recommended 3rd party insurance companies operating there?
2. Do all borders in the island offer car insurance?
3. Are these companies (Sixt and Europcar) allow to cross the border back and forth? If not, which are recommended renting companies to do so?

Comment: Can you take a bus to the north and rent a car there?

Comment: @gerrit: That's one of the solution. But, it requires extra precious time to do so.